# Inkscape: anti-aliased png icon loses colours on move to Windows?

Tags: png, inkscape

This has got to be a dumb question... I just installed Inkscape, and very quickly managed to draw an anti-aliased png icon, 16x16, which is just a hollow circle with a colour gradient (I've also tried with a grayscale gradient, with the same result). I created the image as an svg, and exported a png bitmap. When I read the png bitmap back into Inkscape, it looks exactly like an anti-aliased circle should look.

Here's the problem. If I read the png into Paint Shop Pro, running on Windows, it doesn't look the same. The same pixels are set, but the colours have changed in such a way that the image is now just jaggy, rather than anti-aliased. The colour range seems to have shrunk. I can't find anything in Inkscape that tells me how many colours there are in the image, or what they are, but PSP is reporting that there are 40 24-bit colours in the image, which seems about right. They're just the wrong colours; they're more saturated.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

### EDIT

Ok, sorted out a couple of screenshots, at http://cyconix.com/pub. circle-blue.png is the original 16x16 png, created on Inkscape. When I read back the png from this URL, and:

(1) load it into PSP on Windows, and then take a screenshot, I get psp-screenshot.jpg;

(2) load it into Inkscape on Linux, and then take a screenshot, I get inkscape-screenshot.jpeg.

There seems to be some disagreement among Windows programs on how to interpret the png. Paint, PSP and 'Quicktime PictureViewer' show the blocky version. 'Windows Picture and Fax Viewer' appears to show it correctly (I can't be sure). Note that I'm running XP, and these are old versions of the programs.

Comment: Just to be sure, did you load the svg file back into Inkscape or the png?

Comment: The png. The png does look good - properly anti-aliased at the pixel level, with a gradual tail-off of pixels.

Comment: Any chance of screenshots from both Inkscape and Paint Shop Pro?

Comment: How do I do that? I'll have a quick search and see if I can post them here...

Answer (score 0):

It seems PSP is not loading the alpha channel, that's why you don't see it antialiased.
Maybe your version of PSP can't handle alpha channel.

Some applications don't support transparency at all (e.g. Windows Paint), and some applications don't support an alpha channel, they just support a binary transparency (on or off).

Your PNG has a full alpha channel, i.e. 255 levels of transparency on each pixel, that's how Inkscape exports it.
If you don't need transparency you can add a white backgroud in Inkscape and you will get a correctly antialiased image on white.

When I want to edit raster images I use Gimp.

Comment: It is an old version of PSP (7), but it does handle alpha - I've just combined two png's via an alpha channel. I've also found something rather curious. If I use Inkscape to make a 32x64 png, which is made up of eight of the 16x16 png files, then PSP shows it correctly. No problems at all. I've also found that Visio 2000 has *exactly* the same issue - it reads the 16x16 png 'incorrectly', but the 32x64 png 'correctly'. I know these are old programs, but this at least points to Inkscape doing something unusual with small pngs.

Comment: You can try to edit the png file in other program, like gimp, and save it as a new image, then you can see if it is an inkscape problem.